# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f080099

Tags: android, android-studio

I am working on an Android Program and tried testing it on different devices. Other devices seems okay but on this device, I got these errors. This device's API Level is 23.

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f080099
    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1572)
    at android.content.res.VivoResources.getValue(VivoResources.java:191)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:328)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:193)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:186)
    at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getIcon(MenuItemImpl.java:491)
    at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView.initialize(NavigationMenuItemView.java:118)
    at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.onBindViewHolder(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:429)
    at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.onBindViewHolder(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:352)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6673)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6714)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5647)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5913)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5752)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5748)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2232)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1559)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1519)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:614)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3812)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3529)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4082)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16947)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5711)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:396)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16947)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5711)
    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1195)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16947)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5711)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:396)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16947)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5711)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:2001)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1844)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1753)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16947)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5711)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:396)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16947)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5711)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:2001)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1844)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1753)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16947)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5711)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:396)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333
```

Pray tell if you need more information. Thank you. I am a novice.

Comment: Could you please post the java code which creates the error?

Comment: @JacobCelestine     public CharSequence getAccessibilityClassName() {
        return FrameLayout.class.getName();
    }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have an error in the `res/menu/drawer.xml` or whatever file you inflate there... it bugs out at:

> MenuItemImpl.getIcon(MenuItemImpl.java:491)

the reason for it being device-specific is, that the resource might not exist for the display density, which the device requires. one easy fix would be to use `drawable-nodpi` and use vector icons instead.

Comment: is it possible to create only one (1) drawer.xml for all my activities?

Comment: you don't need several drawers, hence this orinary it the main navigation - you just have to provide the icon drawable resources for all screen densities, or use `SVG` vectors which can be scaled... I'm almost certain you have one `PNG` or `WEBP` icon in that menu, which does not exist for all densities (sizes).

Comment: Yes there is a .png the rest are vectors

Comment: if I am to change that PNG file, which must I choose, Clip Art or Local File(SVG, PSD)?

Comment: @Mark-LuigiBatoctoy the `XML` which contains `SVG` might be corrupted and can for some reason not rendered... would suggest to backup the drawer.xml and remove all icons, then add them back in one by one and see when it starts crashing; a corrupt xml drawable could also be the reason.

Comment: Thank you! It is all fine now. For SVG, my minimumSDK build is 19 so i cannot change all the icons to SVG. Thank you thank you !

Comment: @Mark-LuigiBatoctoy with the Support Library it is possible to render these to PNG: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html for backwards compatibility.